# How do I pass a property in Apigee's target endpoint?

Tags: json, api, apigee

I am exposing an endpoint e.g. `example.com/transactions` via Apigee. I am using a Proxy endpoint which routes to my Target endpoint.

If I hit `xxx.apigee.net/transactions`, i get back my entire payload just as if I hit `example.com/transactions`. So far so good.

However, if I want to view one specific transaction, going to `xxx.apigee.net/transactions/1` does not work. How can I make Apigee understand it needs to pass `/1` to the underlying proxy endpoint so that it returns the same as `example.com/transactions/1`?

How can I pass the {resource-path} variable?

Answer (score 0):

The Apigee API gateway passes the value through already. There is no need for additional manipulation.